# Error when trying to create a new object of my class

Tags: java, java-threads

I try to create a new object of my class ReaderWriter with `ReaderWriter readerWriter = new ReaderWriter();`, but I am getting an error message.

I hope you can help me, because I don't know what I am doing wrong.
I just want to create a new object of my class...

**Error:** `No enclosing instance of type Reader is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Reader (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of Reader).`

Error occurs at main methode:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
            ReaderWriter readerWriter = new ReaderWriter();
```

**Code:**

```
import BSsync.Lock;
import BSsync.Condition;

class File {
    String content = "";
}

class Reader extends Thread {
    ReaderWriter readerWriter;
    String identifier;

    public Reader (String identifier, ReaderWriter readerWriter) {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        this.readerWriter = readerWriter;
    }

    public void run () {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String message = readerWriter.read(identifier);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class Writer extends Thread {
        ReaderWriter readerWriter;
        String identifier;

        public Writer (String identifier, ReaderWriter readerWriter) {
            this.identifier = identifier;
            this.readerWriter = readerWriter;
        }

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                String message = "Message " + i + " of writer " + identifier;
                readerWriter.write(message);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class  ReaderWriter {
        final static int MAX_READERS = 3;

        Lock mutex = new Lock();
        Condition okToWrite = mutex.newCondition();
        Condition maxReaders = mutex.newCondition();
        int activeReaders = 0;
        boolean busy = false;
        File file = new File();

        public String read (String identifierOfReader) {
            readStart();
            String result = file.content;
            System.out.println("\tReader " + identifierOfReader + " has read: " + result);
            readStop();
            return result;
        }

        public void write (String content) {
            writeStart();
            System.out.println(content + " was written");
            file.content = content;
            writeStop();
        }

        private void readStart() {
            mutex.lock();
            
            while (busy) {
                okToWrite.await();
            }
            
            while (activeReaders + 1 > MAX_READERS) {
                maxReaders.await();
            }
            
            activeReaders++;
            mutex.unlock();
        }

        private void readStop() {
            mutex.lock();
            activeReaders--;
            maxReaders.signalAll();
            if (activeReaders == 0) {
                okToWrite.signalAll();
            }
            mutex.unlock();
        }

        private void writeStart() {
            mutex.lock();
            while (busy || activeReaders > 0) {
                okToWrite.await();
            }
            busy = true;
            mutex.unlock();
        }

        private void writeStop() {
            mutex.lock();
            busy = false;
            okToWrite.signalAll();
            mutex.unlock();
        }
    
    
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            ReaderWriter readerWriter = new ReaderWriter();
            
            
            Writer writerA = new Writer("A", readerWriter);
            Writer writerB = new Writer("B", readerWriter);
            writerA.start();
            writerB.start();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                Reader r = new Reader(Integer.toString(i), readerWriter);
                r.start();
            }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Do not embed your classes like this (except if you know what it is used for). One class, one file if you are a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick a class definition inside a class, you want to mark it `static` unless you really know what you are doing. If you fail to do this, the class becomes an 'inner class' (whereas if you add `static`, the terminology is that it is a 'nested class'), and inner classes have invisible extra stuff. Specifically, a `final` field of the enclosing class's type, and all constructors gain an additional parameter that sets this secret final field, except instead of `new ReaderWriter(outerInstance)`, the syntax is `outerInstance.new ReaderWriter()` which looks bizarre (i.e. is unfamiliar to many java programmers which isn't great), but the `outerInstance.` part is filled in for you **if** you are in the right context. In `main`, you are in a static method, so no such instance is readily available, so you'd need to make one. More crucially I doubt that your intent was that any given ReaderWriter class has an associated value for 'Reader', so, just.. mark it static:

```
static class ReaderWriter { ... }
```